# How to multiply two lists and store its sum in a 2D array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to multiply two 2D array in such a way that first array's row will be multiplied with the column of the second one.

So I transposed the second array so that its column changed to its transposedone's row. Then I extracted two rows from the 2D arrays one by one and treated them as two simple list, multiplied them and stored them in another list.

I want to store them as 00 (row-column) element of the resultant 2D array. How can I do it?

```
NO_OF_ROWS_A=int(input("Enter the no. of rows in A: "))
NO_OF_COLUMNS_A=int(input("Enter the no. of columns in A: "))
NO_OF_ROWS_B=int(input("Enter the no. of rows in B : "))
NO_OF_COLUMNS_B=int(input("Enter the no. of columns in B: "))

mat_A=[[] for i in range(NO_OF_ROWS_A)]
for i in range(NO_OF_ROWS_A):
    for j in range (NO_OF_COLUMNS_A):
        print("Enter",i,j,"element for mat A: ")
        a=int(input())
        mat_A[i].append(a)

mat_B=[[] for i in range(NO_OF_ROWS_B)]
for i in range(NO_OF_ROWS_B):
    for j in range (NO_OF_COLUMNS_B):
        print("Enter",i,j,"element for mat B: ")
        b=int(input())
        mat_B[i].append(b)

import itertools
mat_B_trans = list(itertools.zip_longest(*mat_B))#transposes B to change its col into row

sum_list_x=0

mat_C=[[] for i in range(NO_OF_ROWS_A)]
for i in range(NO_OF_ROWS_A):
    for j in range(NO_OF_COLUMNS_B):
        for i in range(NO_OF_ROWS_A):#extracts row of A
            list_row_a=mat_A[i]
        for j in range(NO_OF_COLUMNS_B):#extracts row of trans_B which is col of B
            list_column_b=mat_B_trans[i]
        list_temp_multiple=[a*b for a,b in zip(list_row_a, list_column_b)]#list of multiples of same indices of A & B
        sum_list=sum(list_temp_multiple)#sum of prev list elemets
        sum_list_x=sum_list_x + sum_list

        c = sum_list_x
        mat_C[i].append(c)
print(mat_C)
```

Comment: Pro tip: `zip(*some_list_of_lists)` transposes rows and columns.

Comment: Also, you can loop over lists *directly*; `for elem in somelist:`. `for i in range()` is rarely if ever needed in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org), your entire program could be written as:

```
import numpy as np

mat_A = np.matrix(input('Enter matrix A: '))
mat_B = np.matrix(input('Enter matrix B: '))
mat_C = mat_A * mat_B
print(mat_C)
```

yields

```
Enter matrix A: [[1,2], [3,4]]
Enter matrix B: [[5,6], [7,8]]
[[19 22]
 [43 50]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Would the following work for you:

```
[sum(a * b for a, b in zip(*combined_row)) for combined_row in zip(mat_A, zip(*mat_B))]
```

This transposes `mat_B`, zips the two matrices per row, then multiplies the rows per-column and sums the multiplied values, making *one* list of values.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[sum(a*b for a,b in zip(mat_A_row,mat_B_col)) for mat_A_col in zip(*mat_B)] for mat_A_row in mat_A]
```

zip(*X) returns the transpose of matrix X in tuple format